# ListBox.TopIndex unable to store 70000 as its datatype is int

Tags: winforms, listbox

Current in my situation my listbox has 75000 items and on scroll i am setting the topindex value on scrolling event. But after storing more than 65536 it comes back to starting point.
As ListBox.TopIndex datatype is Int so again it is setting topindex starting from zero but i need to store 70000 or 75000 in this to set the top index as my listbox contains more than 70000 items.

Is it possible to set this?

Comment: Why do you need 70000+ items in your listbox?  Do you realize how painful that will be for your users to navigate through?

Comment: yeah thats fine, but this is the requirement, for that we have textbox which filter listbox with character inserted to textbox. But this situation looks bug user scroll down the listbox it scrolls back to starting point as topindex goes off to max limit of Int Datatype.. Please help if its posible

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comments, using a textbox to filter the list should be a helpful way to make a large dataset reasonable to process for your users.  In this case you will have to handle the TextChanged event for your textbox.  Since you will constantly be changing the datasource for the listbox, you will not be able to store indexes across filter changes, you will need to track the current selected or top text value to maintain perspective in the list.

Here is a sample handler that should give you a starting point (dataItems is your master list of items):

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isSelected = listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1;
        string current = "";

        if (isSelected)
            current = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
            listBox1.DataSource = dataItems;
        else
            listBox1.DataSource = dataItems.Where(x => x.StartsWith(textBox1.Text)).ToList();
        if (isSelected)
            listBox1.SelectedItem = current;
        listBox1.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, but as u can see we have already implemented textbox filtering, but when user scroll down the list instead of filtering, it again comes to starting point after some scroll, this look buggy from user point of you.. Does any solution available or I have to change design..

Comment: We'd need to see some of your code to understand.  What are you trying to accomplish with setting the topindex?  What are you changing as the user scrolls?